# Passing Keycloak token to another application

Tags: java, token, keycloak

We have a java application that is using Keycloak/Redhat SSO to login.
This application needs to provide a link in one of the jsp that redirects to a page in another Java EE application running on Jboss on a different server, and pass it the form data.
The second app is not using keycloak or SSO

We are thinking to pass the jwt token that we receive from keycloak to the second application. This token should have the userid and some other information that will allow the second app to check the role of that userid from the database and create a session cookie then forward them to the page without forwarding them to login page.

We got the authentication with Keycloak done in the first app and I have a userPrincipal object in my httpServletRequest.userPrincipal in the first app

I am not sure how to pass the principal or jwt token from the jsp on app1 to app2.
I looked at response.sendredirect() and setHeader but it doesn't seem to work when it's received on app2

What would be the best way to send this jwt token other than in a form parameter ?
should we serialize it and send it as json string ?  Because if we send the token string itself it's encrypted and not sure how to decrypt it on the other app.

Thank you

Comment: both applications are behind firewall and not publicly facing, so we really need to check what userid is being passed and determine the role. But we don't want to pass the userid itself directly as a param

Comment: Why not? If the token is not encrypted, you basically pass it around "directly" since the token is just Base64 encoded. On the other hand, the token will be no good for the other application if it cannot verify the signature of the token, thus making the system vulnerable to attacks.